# How can I simplify my deserialization framework?

Tags: serialization, d

I have a Serialization interface which is designed to encapsulate the differences between XML/JSON/binary serialization for my application. It looks something like this:

```
interface Serialization {
    bool isObject();
    int opApply(int delegate(string member, Serialization value) del); //iterate object
    ...
    int toInt();   //this part is ugly, but without template member overloading, I
    long toLong(); //figure out any way to apply generics here, so all basic types
    ...            //have a toType primitive
    string toString();
}
class JSONSerialization : Serialization {
    private JSON json;
    ...
    long toLong() {
        enforce(json.type == JSON_TYPE.NUMBER, SerializationException.IncorrectType);
        return cast(long)json.toNumber();
    }
    ...
}
```

So, what I then set up is a set of templates for registering type deserializers and calling them:

```
...
registerTypeDeserializer!Vec3(delegate Vec3(Serialization s) {
    return Vec3(s[0].toFloat, s[1].toFloat, s[2].toFloat);
});
...
auto v = parseJSON("some file").deserialize!Vec3;
...
registerTypeDeserializer!Light(delegate Light(Serialization s) {
    return new Light(s["intensity"].toFloat, s["position"].deserialize!Vec3);
});
```

This works well for structs and simple classes, and with the new parameter identifier tuple and parameter default value tuple I should even be able to add automatic deserializer generation. However, I don't really like the inconsistency between basic and user defined types, and more importantly, complex types have to rely on global state to acquire references:

```
static MaterialLibrary materials;
registerTypeDeserializer!Model(delegate Model(Serialization s) {
    return new Model(materials.borrow(s["material"].toString), ...);
});
```

That's where it really falls apart. Because I can't (without a proliferation of register deserializer functions) pass other parameters to the deserializer, I'm having difficulty avoiding ugly global factories. I've thought about eliminating the deserialize template, and requiring a deserialize function (which could accept multiple parameters) for each user defined type, but that seems like a lot of work for e.g. POD structs.

So, how can I simplify this design, and hopefully avoid tons of boilerplate deserializers, while still allowing me to inject object factories appropriately, instead of assigning them globally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic types can be read using `readf` \ `formattedRead`, so you can create a wrapper function that uses this `formattedRead` it possible, otherwise it uses a static function from the desired type to read the value. Something like this:

```
auto _readFrom(T)(string s){
    static if(__traits(compiles,(readf("",cast(T*)(null))))){
        T result;
        formattedRead(s,"%s",&result);
        return result;
    }else{
        return T.readFrom(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've actually not had any problems parsing the values. I'm using std.conv to read into a JSON object tree currently, but in the future I'd like to be able to use a custom binary format, thus the Serialization interface abstracting away the details of the serialized format. What I'm struggling with is how to manage those "static functions from the desired type", particularly when there are creation dependencies. If I use a template to homogenize all the deserializer functions, how do I pass supporting parameters in to them?

Comment: Why do you have to pass extra serialization parameters in the first place? An object's serialized string needs to hold all the information to recreate the object.

Comment: Because some of my types hold references to objects that they don't own, such as the Model/Material example. A Material will be shared among multiple Models, so the Model's deserializer needs to be able to retrieve the correct Material from a collection, rather than creating a new one. That collection (MaterialLibrary) will have to be either global, or passed in to the deserializer.

Comment: OK, how about this: the static `readForm` functions won't get a `string` as their parameter - they'll get a `Deserialization` object. That `Deserialization` object, beside passing the next part of the string to deserialize, will also store all the objects already deserialize(with some kind of a key). Deserialization static functions that need to access that information will be able to do it, and functions that don't need that information(standalone objects) will not be bothered by the extra information, because they only get a pointer to an object.

Comment: Ha! I think that's it. In fact, I already am passing around the Serialization, which is basically a tree of objects. So, using your idea, when I deserialize the main section for an object, I will just need to replace references to that object in the tree with a Serialization wrapper. Thanks Idan! I think this has great potential.